# I didn't ask to be torn apart and put back together again

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, knowledge

> Bippity boppity boo!
>   I don't really know how to shoot;
>   By the end, your love for me grew,
>   By the end, I knew what I must do.
>   You can be sure that when danger looms,
>   I will prevent our impending doom-
>   You can count on me and the 'coon!
>   In the end, it's not hard to choose-
>   I'm the favorite, and we are _____.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding text to get to 30 characters and the answer is

> Groot